# Remove About Us page

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, ce-1.9.2.2

In **magento 1.9.2.2**, how to remove **about us** page from top navigation only.

The image is shown below..

[image]

Is there any way to remove it from admin panel?

Comment: By default, the About Us page is not displayed in top navigation on Magento 1.9.2.2, I guess you're using a custom theme ? Could you post the content of your custom theme local.xml file if you have one ?

Comment: Yes I am using a theme. Ok let me fetch it for You.

Comment: Where do I find this page?

Comment: `yourthme/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` check there about us link

Comment: <?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>

<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>

Comment: app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/local.xml

Comment: There is no such page

Comment: can you share your site url??

Comment: http://www.urdubazarlhr.com/